# Secure random token in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, securestring

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838624/nodejs-send-email-on-registration/8842959#8842959) Erik needs to generate a secure random token in Node.js. There's the method `crypto.randomBytes` that generates a random Buffer. However, the base64 encoding in node is not url-safe, it includes `/` and `+` instead of `-` and `_`. Therefore, the easiest way to generate such token I've found is

```
require('crypto').randomBytes(48, function(ex, buf) {
    token = buf.toString('base64').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');
});
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: What is the rest of the code?

Comment: There's nothing more needed. What rest would you like to see?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work, was just unsure of how you threw it in, but got a better grasp of the concept

Comment: I made an npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-random-string

Comment: Shameless self-plug, I created yet another npm package: [tokgen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tokgen). You can specify allowed characters using a range syntax similar to character classes in regular expressions (`'a-zA-Z0-9_-'`).

Comment: [rand-token](https://github.com/sehrope/node-rand-token) works for me

Comment: This may be convenient for anyone who'd like a specific string length. The 3/4th's is to handle the base conversion.

    /*returns a base64 encoded string of length*/
    function randomString(length){
      return crypto.randomBytes(length*3/4).toString('base64');
    }

Works nice for those databases with those character limits.

Comment: Sync: `require('crypto').randomBytes(48).toString('base64').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');
`

Comment: This works well

`node -e "require('crypto').randomBytes(68^12, function(ex, buf) { console.log(buf.toString('base64')) });"`

Answer (score 475, accepted):

Try [crypto.randomBytes()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback):

```
require('crypto').randomBytes(48, function(err, buffer) {
  var token = buffer.toString('hex');
});
```

The 'hex' encoding works in node v0.6.x or newer.

Comment: That seems better, thanks! A 'base64-url' encoding would be nice, though.

Comment: Tantek did some interesting work on that: http://tantek.pbworks.com/w/page/24308279/NewBase64

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I think the OP simply wanted the already-standard RFC 3548 section 4 "Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet". IMO, replacing the characters is "elegant enough".

Comment: If you're looking for the above as a bash one-liner, you can do `node -e "require('crypto').randomBytes(48, function(ex, buf) { console.log(buf.toString('hex')) });"`

Comment: And you can always do `buf.toString('base64')` to get a Base64-encoded number.

Comment: I made it into an npm module for easy installation. `npm -g install secretkey`

Comment: @thejh Is using a base64 encoding safer than a hex encoding?

Comment: @kittyminky2 No, but it's shorter.

Comment: See [this answser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25690754/1480391) below for **base 64 encoding** with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet

Comment: A slightly more compact version of Dmitry's excellent one-liner: `node -p "require('crypto').randomBytes(48).toString('hex');"` (subbing `base64` for `hex`) if desired

Comment: What are the chances it will repeat or generate the same token?

Comment: I'm sorry is it just me who thinks limiting A-Z to only A-F, severely lowers surface of attack. Why are we limiting ourselves to hex highest alphabet?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, assuming you are still using all of the 48 bytes generated in this example, the hex string will simply be longer than the base64 one, but have the same amount of randomness

Answer (score 348):

Synchronous option in-case if you are not a JS expert like me. Had to spend some time on how to access the inline function variable

```
var token = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
```

Comment: Also in case you don't want to have everything nested. Thanks!

Comment: While this definitely works, do note that in most cases you'll want the async option demonstrated in thejh's answer.

Comment: `const generateToken = (): Promise<string> => new Promise(resolve => randomBytes(48, (err, buffer) => resolve(buffer.toString('hex'))));`

Comment: @Triforcey can you explain why you usually would want the async option?

Comment: @thomas Random data can take a while to calculate depending on hardware. In some cases if the computer runs out of random data it'll just return something in it's place. However in other cases it's possible the computer will delay the return of random data (which is actually what you would want) resulting in a slow call.

Comment: Here's it explained well from Wikipedia: "The speed at which entropy can be harvested from natural sources is dependent on the underlying physical phenomena being measured. Thus, sources of naturally occurring "true" entropy are said to be blocking" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Comment: You can also use promisify function from the built in "util" module to avoid callback function.
const token = await promisify(crypto.randomBytes)(48);

Note that await can only be used in async function.

Answer (score 110):

### 1. Using nanoid third party library [NEW!]

---

> A tiny, secure, URL-friendly, unique string ID generator for JavaScript

https://github.com/ai/nanoid

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
const id = nanoid(48);
```

### 2. Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet

---

[Page 7 of RCF 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7) describes how to encode in base 64 with URL safety.

This is [natively supported by Node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/26512) >=v14.18.0:

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");

/** Sync */
function randomStringAsBase64Url(size) {
  return crypto.randomBytes(size).toString("base64url");
}
```

Usage example:

```js
randomStringAsBase64Url(20);
// Returns "AXSGpLVjne_f7w5Xg-fWdoBwbfs" which is 27 characters length.
```

Note that the returned string length will not match with the size argument (size != final length).

If you are using Node.js <v14.18.0 you can use an existing library like [base64url](https://www.npmjs.org/package/base64url) to do the job. The function will be:

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");
const base64url = require("base64url");
    
/** Sync */
function randomStringAsBase64Url(size) {
  return base64url(crypto.randomBytes(size));
}
```

### 3. Crypto random values from limited set of characters

---

> Beware that with this solution the generated random string is not uniformly distributed.

You can also build a strong random string from a limited set of characters like that:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

/** Sync */
function randomString(length, chars) {
  if (!chars) {
    throw new Error("Argument 'chars' is undefined");
  }

  const charsLength = chars.length;
  if (charsLength > 256) {
    throw new Error("Argument 'chars' should not have more than 256 characters"
      + ", otherwise unpredictability will be broken");
  }

  const randomBytes = crypto.randomBytes(length);
  let result = new Array(length);

  let cursor = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    cursor += randomBytes[i];
    result[i] = chars[cursor % charsLength];
  }

  return result.join("");
}

/** Sync */
function randomAsciiString(length) {
  return randomString(length,
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");
}
```

Usage example:

```
randomAsciiString(20);
// Returns "rmRptK5niTSey7NlDk5y" which is 20 characters length.

randomString(20, "ABCDEFG");
// Returns "CCBAAGDGBBEGBDBECDCE" which is 20 characters length.
```

Comment: @Lexynux **Solution 1** (Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet) because it is the strongest solution in term of security. This solution only encode the key and does not interfere with the key production process.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Do you have any working example to share with the community? It will be welcomed?

Comment: Beware that the generated random string is not uniformly distributed. An easy example to show this is, that for a character set of length 255, and a string length of 1, the chance of the first character appearing is twice as high.

Comment: @Dodekeract Yes, you are talking about solution 2.. That's why solution 1 is way more strong

Comment: I've added nanoid third party library in my response https://github.com/ai/nanoid

Comment: @FlorianWendelborn may I ask you explain a bit your point. Is there any difference between 255 char set and hex string of generated buffer?

Comment: @AlexeySh. a bit hard to remember as this was nearly a decade ago by now. I think it’s about the danger of just using mod/division rest to hash which character you get out of the randomness. For example, if you roll a random byte (0-255) and then only provide 255 possible characters the random 0 = random 255 = first possible character, so it’s not uniform

Comment: For option 2, note that since Node v14.18.0 'base64url' is supported as a built-in encoding, so you can just `crypto.randomBytes(size).toString('base64url')` now.

Comment: Yeah right @TimPerry I've open a Node.js issue ling time ago and they accepted it! https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/26512

Answer (score 22):

As of Node.js 14.18 and 15.7, url-safe base64 encoding support [is built-in](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffers-and-character-encodings):

```js
const token = crypto.randomBytes(48).toString('base64url');
```

If you want to use the async version (because the function may have to wait for entropy), it can be promisified to align better with modern patterns:

```js
const randomBytesAsync = util.promisify(crypto.randomBytes);

const token = (await randomBytesAsync(48)).toString('base64url');
```

Answer (score 21):

The up-to-date *right way* to do this asynchronously using ES 2016 standards of async and await (as of Node 7) would be the following:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function generateToken({ stringBase = 'base64', byteLength = 48 } = {}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    crypto.randomBytes(byteLength, (err, buffer) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(buffer.toString(stringBase));
      }
    });
  });
}

async function handler(req, res) {
   // default token length
   const newToken = await generateToken();
   console.log('newToken', newToken);

   // pass in parameters - adjust byte length
   const shortToken = await generateToken({byteLength: 20});
   console.log('newToken', shortToken);
}
```

This works out of the box in Node 7 without any Babel transformations

Comment: I've updated this example to incorporate the newer method of passing named parameters as described here: http://2ality.com/2011/11/keyword-parameters.html

Answer (score 14):

Random URL and filename string safe (1 liner)

```js
Crypto.randomBytes(48).toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\=/g, '');
```

Comment: A wonderful answer in it's simplicity! Just be aware that it could stall the event loop in an indeterministic way (only relevant if it's used often, in a somewhat loaded, time-sensitive system). Otherwise, do the same thing, but using the async version of randomBytes. See https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback

Answer (score 11):

With async/await and [promisification](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const randomBytes = Util.promisify(crypto.randomBytes)
const plain = (await randomBytes(24)).toString('base64').replace(/\W/g, '')
```

Generates something similar to `VjocVHdFiz5vGHnlnwqJKN0NdeHcz8eM`

Answer (score 10):

Check out:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(length/2)).toString('hex').slice(0,length);
```

Comment: Nice! Absolutely underrated solution. Would be great if you rename "length" to "desiredLength" and initiate it with a value before using it :)

Comment: For anyone wondering, the `ceil` and `slice` calls are necessary for desired lengths that are odd. For even lengths, they don't change anything.

Answer (score 8):

**[crypto-random-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-random-string)** is a nice module for this.

```
const cryptoRandomString = require('crypto-random-string');
 
cryptoRandomString({length: 10});                          // => '2cf05d94db'
cryptoRandomString({length: 10, type: 'base64'});          // => 'YMiMbaQl6I'
cryptoRandomString({length: 10, type: 'url-safe'});        // => 'YN-tqc8pOw'
cryptoRandomString({length: 10, type: 'numeric'});         // => '8314659141'
cryptoRandomString({length: 6, type: 'distinguishable'});  // => 'CDEHKM'
cryptoRandomString({length: 10, type: 'ascii-printable'}); // => '`#Rt8$IK>B'
cryptoRandomString({length: 10, type: 'alphanumeric'});    // => 'DMuKL8YtE7'
cryptoRandomString({length: 10, characters: 'abc'});       // => 'abaaccabac'
```

`cryptoRandomString.async(options)` add `.async` if you want to get a `promise`.

Answer (score 5):

in your terminal just write

```bash
node -e "console.log(crypto.randomBytes(48).toString('hex'))"
```

Or in your code use:

```js
const randomToken = () => {
   crypto.randomBytes(48).toString('hex');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at `real_ates` ES2016 way, it's more correct.

### ECMAScript 2016 (ES7) way

```
import crypto from 'crypto';

function spawnTokenBuf() {
    return function(callback) {
        crypto.randomBytes(48, callback);
    };
}

async function() {
    console.log((await spawnTokenBuf()).toString('base64'));
};
```

### Generator/Yield Way

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var co = require('co');

function spawnTokenBuf() {
    return function(callback) {
        crypto.randomBytes(48, callback);
    };
}

co(function* () {
    console.log((yield spawnTokenBuf()).toString('base64'));
});
```

Comment: @Jeffpowrs Indeed, Javascript is upgrading :) Lookup Promises and Generators!

Comment: try await, another ECMA7 promise handler

Comment: I think that you should make the ES 2016 the first example on this as it is moving towards the "right way to do it" in most cases

Comment: I added an answer of my own below that was specific to Node (using require instead of import). Was there a particular reason why you're using import? Do you have babel running?

Comment: @real_ate Indeed I was, I've reverted to using CommonJS until import is officially supported.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-extra has a method for it :)

```
var value = crypto.random(/* desired length */)
```

Comment: great! But isnt it `.randomString (length, charset)` (see [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-extra#randomstring-length-charset)). So you could user for example `crypto.randomString(12)`.

Answer (score 3):

The npm module [anyid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/anyid) provides flexible API to generate various kinds of string ID / code.

To generate random string in A-Za-z0-9 using 48 random bytes:

```
const id = anyid().encode('Aa0').bits(48 * 8).random().id();
// G4NtiI9OYbSgVl3EAkkoxHKyxBAWzcTI7aH13yIUNggIaNqPQoSS7SpcalIqX0qGZ
```

To generate fixed length alphabet only string filled by random bytes:

```
const id = anyid().encode('Aa').length(20).random().id();
// qgQBBtDwGMuFHXeoVLpt
```

Internally it uses `crypto.randomBytes()` to generate random.

Answer (score 2):

Simple function that gets you a token that is URL safe and has base64 encoding! It's a combination of 2 answers from above.

```js
const randomToken = () => {
    crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('base64').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

0 dependency free solution... Works in browsers, deno & nodejs (with new global web crypto)

```js
const random = size => btoa(
  String.fromCharCode(
    ...crypto.getRandomValues(
      new Uint8Array(size)
    )
  )
).replaceAll('+', 'x').replaceAll('/', 'I').slice(0, size)

for (let i = 5; i--;) console.log(random(16))
```

All doe I would just have used one single uint8array \w predefined length and called `crypto.getRandomValues` whenever I need something uniq (and slice it if i have to) and never deal with strings or base64, base64 is just unnecessary overhead.
(allocating lots of buffer to fast can be costly)

```js
const buf256 = new Uint8Array(256)
const random = crypto.getRandomValues.bind(crypto, buf256)

for (let i = 5; i--;) random()//.slice()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `random-token` **lib**. it's very easy to use . :)

```
var randomToken = require('random-token').create('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxzyABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789');
var token = randomToken(16);
```

And also you can not use **different salt**

````
var randomToken = require('random-token');
var token = randomToken(16); // output -> d8d4kd29c40f021 ```
````